# How to "groupby" year, column1 and calculate the average on column 2?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
year         vehicule number_of_passengers
2017-01-09   bus      100
2017-11-02   car      150
2018-08-01   car      180
2016-08-09   bus      100
...
```

I would like to have something like this (the average number of passengers per year and per vehicule) :

```
year   vehicule avg_number_of_passengers
2018   car      123.5
2018   bus      213.7
2017   ...      ...
...
```

I've tried with some groupby() but can't find the good command. Can you help me ?

Comment: `df.groupby([df.year.dt.year,'vehicule']).mean().reset_index()` ? if year is not already a datetime convert ir by `df.year=pd.to_datetime(df.year)`

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you !